update plot on changing values
I am trying to update a fig when selecting values in GUI. When i change the value the start_analytics def is initiated whihc generates the plotly fig. but it does not update the plot in web page.
def start_analytics(state):
        merged_df = pd.concat([x_df, y_df, z_df], axis=1)
        selected_df = merged_df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']]
        print(selected_df.shape[0])
        print(selected_df.head())

        # Using Plotly for an interactive 3D plot
        state.fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Scatter3d(
            x=selected_df['X'],  # X-axis values
            y=selected_df['Y'],  # Y-axis values
            z=selected_df['Z'],  # Z-axis values
            mode='lines',
            line=dict(width=1, color='red'),
            name='RSI Data',
            hovertext=[f"Index of RSI point: {index}" for index in merged_df.index]
        )])

md :
<|{form_visualize.v_selected_instance}|selector|lov={e_available_instances}|type=Instance|adapter={lambda i: (str(i.id), i.name)}|label=Select Instance :|on_change=start_analytics|dropdown|>
<|chart|figure={fig}|height=70vh|>

should i use state.fig to update the plot? i tried this as just fig doesnt really work.
i have a complex robot path with x,y,z to plot and contains 130000+ data points would this be an issue?

This should work. Could you create a complete code that replicates the issue?

https://dash.plotly.com/interactive-graphing Refer to this page should have what you are trying to do
